# OpenOffice Desktop Instance can not be created (com object)

Tags: delphi, com, openoffice.org, delphi-xe7

I have some problems to create an instance of the StarOffice Desktop object.
I used the standard construct below but whenever it comes to the line: `StarDesktop := StarOffice.CreateInstance('com.sun.star.frame.Desktop');`
My StarDesktop Variant stays unassigned. I am pretty sure that the code is ok until there but perhaps something with the OpenOffice installation is messed up.
Is there a way to check the com objects or did somebody had the same problem and could solve it...

```
uses
  ComObj;

procedure OpenOfficeDocument;
var
  StarOffice: Variant;
  StarDesktop: Variant;
begin
  StarOffice := CreateOleObject('com.sun.star.ServiceManager');
  StarDesktop := StarOffice.CreateInstance('com.sun.star.frame.Desktop');
  // StarDesktop is always "unassigned"
....
```

Yes, I know. I should have stated more clearly that I am too 100% sure that it would work normally in a correct environment.
But my question is what could be the cause why it doesn't work. Why the `'com.sun.star.frame.Desktop'` instance is unassigned. I have no option/way to debug it...
And it is a bit unfair to vote me down, I researched for one hour without finding something to explain why it could not work. 
Or how and where to check if something is wrong with the Office installation (I uninstalled and reinstalled it twice already"
Again, I know this will work for others and normally would work for me, but something is wrong at my system and I would like to know some help to point me in the direction what could be wrong in the system (and not in the code example...)

Comment: The StarOffice ServiceManager is assigned after CreateOleObject!

Comment: plz don't use comments for fixing question - edit the question and update the text.

Comment: you may try using SysInternals Process Monitor to see which registry keys files are tried and with which results when you try to create the desktop

Comment: try `getAvailableServiceNames` to see if the Desktop name is even known to the service manager given to you - https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/lang/XMultiServiceFactory.html#getAvailableServiceNames

Answer (score 1):

is OpenOffice installed on client?
doesn't throw any exception?

I'm using [Bernard Marcelly](http://berma.pagesperso-orange.fr/index2.html)'s [Delphi 7 OOo tool](http://berma.pagesperso-orange.fr/Files_en/Delphi_OOo_v14en.zip) and as can you see his code like that;

```
var
  OpenOffice, StarDesktop: Variant;

...
    OpenOffice:= CreateOleObject('com.sun.star.ServiceManager');
    if isNullEmpty(OpenOffice) then Raise Exception.Create('OpenOffice connection is impossible');
    StarDesktop:= OpenOffice.createInstance('com.sun.star.frame.Desktop');
    if isNullEmpty(Result) then Raise Exception.Create(Format('Impossible to create service : %s', ['com.sun.star.frame.Desktop']));
...
```

*'some constants converted to string'*

So, if StarDesktop is null, possible can not access Oo Desktop service. If OpenOffice installed properly some features may be missing, options have to set.

Comment: I suggest;

1-) Try your code on another OpenOffice installed client. 
2-) Try our examples on your client. 
So you can understand is problem about your pc? 
and 
3 - Uninstall your openoffice and try again. If symptoms are same (StarDesktop is null) you can suspect your installation (may be you can download another OpenOffice version) I know it's not the solve but for solve, you should shrink the circle. At least until somebody get answer.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (in my application):

```
class procedure TOpenOffice.Connect;
begin
  if IsConnected then
    Exit;
  try
    FServiceManager := CreateOleObject('com.sun.star.ServiceManager');
  except
    FServiceManager := Null;
  end;
  if VarIsNull(FServiceManager) then
    raise EOpenOfficeException.Create(StrConnectionFailed);
  FDesktop := CreateService('com.sun.star.frame.Desktop');
  FDispatchHelper := CreateService('com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper');
  FIntrospection := CreateService('com.sun.star.beans.Introspection');
  FReflection := CreateService('com.sun.star.reflection.CoreReflection');
end;
```

and:

```
class function TOpenOffice.CreateService(const ServiceName: string): Variant;
begin
  Result := FServiceManager.createInstance(ServiceName);
  if VarIsNull(Result) then
    raise EOpenOfficeException.CreateFmt(StrCouldNotCreateService,     
      [ServiceName]);
end;
```